# HTTP 1.1 on URL is found. hacking suspicion

Tags: wordpress, apache, http, friendly-url

On Wordpress, Whenever I go to

```
http://sawebdev01/company/news-events/press-releases/press-release/pr.php?pr=170
```

instead of getting

```
http://sawebdev01/company/news-events/press-releases/press-release/170
```

I get

```
http://sawebdev01/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/page-templates/170%20HTTP/1.1
```

I'm wondering what's happening and how do I change it back to

```
http://sawebdev01/company/news-events/press-releases/press-release/170
```

My .htaccess looks like this. I know it has been configured correctly because it worked yesterday. It may have something to do with php or the server

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/page-templates/pr.php\?pr=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/page-templates/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !pr\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/page-templates/([^/]+)/ [NC]
RewriteRule .*  /wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/page-templates/pr.php?pr=%1 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Here is my header:

```
X-Pingback: http://sawebdev01/xmlrpc.php
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Tue, 04 Jun 2013 23:09:25 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) DAV/2 PHP/5.4.10 mod_ssl/2.2.15 OpenSSL/1.0.0-fips mod_wsgi/3.2 Python/2.6.6 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.10
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Connection: close
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
```

I have checked on the server access_log inside our linux system. I'm supposed to have this sequence of log that determines that the request was successful:

```
10.0.0.1 - - [03/Jun/2013:09:48:13 -0700] "GET /company/news-events/press-releases/press-release/?pr=169 HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.94 Safari/537.36"
10.0.0.1 - - [03/Jun/2013:09:48:13 -0700] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.94 Safari/537.36"
```

Instead I'm getting this sequence. The first line is good, but the second line should not be existing:

```
10.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2013:09:21:09 -0700] "GET /wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/page-templates/pr.php?pr=169 HTTP/1.1" 301 286 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.94 Safari/537.36"
10.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2013:09:21:09 -0700] "GET /wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/page-templates/169%20HTTP/1.1 HTTP/1.1" 200 44820 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.94 Safari/537.36"
10.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2013:09:21:11 -0700] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.94 Safari/537.36"
```

How do I get rid of **HTTP%201.1** on this URL?

```
http://sawebdev01/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/page-templates/170%20HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: Do you use version control ? Check the status.

Comment: No, we don't currently use version control. Are you suggesting to just revert to last version?

Comment: No I was suggesting diffing the source code against the last verified revision

Comment: We currently don't have version control, do you have any other ideas?

Comment: if your sure it was within the last day, look at file modified times find . -mtime 1 if using linux

Comment: I don't know what happened. But, there was a server log. I checked it, reported it to the people who manages the live HTTP server, and it just suddenly worked in the afternoon.

Comment: likey to be apache set up then glad you got it fixed

Comment: When I tried to check it again by about 9:00 am, we still have the same issue. I don't know if the server goes back or something. I don't know... still trying to find out.